# How to add None for the element in matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I would like to generate a matrix Z_comb which consists of element z with size(len(m),len(m)).
The value of z is from 0 up to (m-1).

For example:

m = [m[0],[m[1],[m[2]] = [4,2,1].

For m[0] = 2, then z[0] = [0,1] and len(m[0]) = 2

For m[1] = 4, then z[1] = [0,1,2,3] and len(m[1]) = 4

For m[2] = 1, then z[2] = [0] and len(m[2]) = 1

What is expected are:
For m[0] = 2, then z[0] = [0,1, None, None] and len(m[0]) = 4

For m[1] = 4, then z[1] = [0,1,2,3] and len(m[1]) = 4

For m[2] = 1, then z[2] = [0, None, None, None] and len(m[2]) = 4

Here the code that I made:

```
    import numpy as np
    m = np.array([2,4,1])
    Z_comb = np.array([np.arange(0,m[0]),np.arange(0,m[1]),np.arange(0,m[2])],dtype=object)
```

The printed result is

Z_comb = array([array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0])], dtype=object)

Expected result:

Z_comb = [[0, 1,None,None], [0, 1, 2,3], [0, None, None, None]]

Can anyone tell me what to modify for the code, please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

##### numpy solution

You can use broadcasting:

```
# input
m = np.array([2,4,1])

N = m.max()
# 4
a = np.arange(N) 
# array([0, 1, 2, 3])

Z_comb = np.where(m[:,None] >= a, a, np.nan)
```

*NB. the output contains [`nan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.NAN) in place of `None` as `None` doesn't really make sense in a numpy array (this would force the `object` dtype and prevent vectorization).*

Output `Z_comb`:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2., nan],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  1., nan, nan]])
```

##### pure python solution

If you want a pure python solution:

```
N = max(m)
Z_comb = [list(range(x))+[None]*(N-x) for x in m]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, None, None],
 [0, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, None, None, None]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a padding question, which has come up often on SO.

Since you want to pad with `None`, we have to make an object dtype array.  Here's an easy way to start:

```
In [60]: res = np.empty((len(m), max(m)), object)    
In [61]: res
Out[61]: 
array([[None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None]], dtype=object)
```

I could have started with an array of 0s, or float dtype filled with `np.nan`.

Then just assign the desire range to each row:

```
In [62]: for i,v in enumerate(m):
    ...:     res[i,:v] = np.arange(v)
    ...:     
In [63]: res
Out[63]: 
array([[0, 1, None, None],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, None, None, None]], dtype=object)
```

Compare that with your way of making a ragged array:

```
In [64]: np.array([np.arange(v) for v in m], object)
Out[64]: array([array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0])], dtype=object)
```

A faster way of padding is to start with a boolean mask such as:

```
In [65]: np.arange(4)<m[:,None]
Out[65]: 
array([[ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False]])
```

Simply multiplying that by the arange produces a 0 filled array:

```
In [66]: np.arange(4) * _
Out[66]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

You can see how that mask relates to the non-None elements of `res`:

```
In [67]: res[Out[65]]
Out[67]: array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0], dtype=object)
```

`itertools` has a `zip_longest`

```
In [79]: list(zip(*zip_longest(*(list(range(i)) for i in m))))
Out[79]: [(0, 1, None, None), (0, 1, 2, 3), (0, None, None, None)]

In [80]: np.array(_)
Out[80]: 
array([[0, 1, None, None],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, None, None, None]], dtype=object)
```